# Android Sqlite Database error

Tags: android

I have made the SqliteDataBase file from the sqlLite Software.
after make the db copy to the assets folder.In db we add dummy data for test.we get the all data from the db.
after get the data from db i am delete the file but the data not remove in the listView.

DBHELPER CLASS

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME="salesman";
    public String DBLOCATION=null;
    private Context mycontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DBNAME,null,10);
        this.mycontext=context;
        this.DBLOCATION="/data/data/" +context.getPackageName()+ "/"+"databases/";
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist=checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist){
        }else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }catch (IOException e){
                throw new Error("Error Copying DataBase");
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkdb=null;
        try {
            String myPath=DBLOCATION+DBNAME;
            checkdb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }catch (SQLException e){
        }
        if (checkdb != null){
            checkdb.close();
        }
        return checkdb != null ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion>oldVersion){
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public List<Shop> getListProduct(){
        Log.v("ListShop","Shop");
        Shop shop=null;
        List<Shop> myShopLIst=new ArrayList<>();
        openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor=myDatabase.rawQuery("Select * From shop",null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.v("CurssorMove","Move");
        Log.v("DB_Path",DBLOCATION + DBNAME);
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            shop= new Shop(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1));
            myShopLIst.add(shop);
            Log.v("Name",shop.getName());
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        close();
        return myShopLIst;
    }
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = mycontext.getAssets().open(DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DBLOCATION + DBNAME;
        Log.v("DB_Path",outFileName);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        Log.v("MainActivity", "DbCoppied");
    }

    public  void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String mypath=DBLOCATION+DBNAME;
        myDatabase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized  void close()
    {
        if (myDatabase!=null)
        {
            myDatabase.close();
            super.close();
        }
    }
    public boolean addShop(String aName,String aAddress,String acontact){
        if (aName.isEmpty() ||aAddress.isEmpty() || acontact.isEmpty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            myDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put("name",aName);
            values.put("address",aAddress);
            values.put("contact",acontact);
            myDatabase.insert("shop",null,values);
            myDatabase.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Shop> myShopList;
    private ListShopAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lvshop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
                myDbHelper.copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Unable to Create Databse");
            }
            try {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                throw e;
            }
            lvshop=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_shop);
            myShopList=myDbHelper.getListProduct();
            adapter=new ListShopAdapter(MainActivity.this,myShopList);
            lvshop.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

if i add the data into the db the data add but not shown in the db but in listView data show
add function in the DataBaseHelper
```

Comment: Help me understand this. You are updating the database but the `ListView` does not reflect this change?

Comment: You have to update your listview after data is deleted then only your ListView is update with bank data. Please look for onNotifyPropertyChanged event in android. http://www.androidauthority.com/data-binding-in-android-709747/